# How to understand curry and function composition using Lodash flow?

Tags: functional-programming, lodash

```
import {flow, curry} from 'lodash';

const add = (a, b) => a + b;

const square = n => n * n;

const tap = curry((interceptor, n) => {
    interceptor(n);
    return n;
});

const trace2 = curry((message, n) => {
    return tap((n) => console.log(`${message} is  ${n}`), n);
});

const trace = label => {
    return tap(x => console.log(`== ${ label }:  ${ x }`));
};


const addSquare = flow([add, trace('after add'), square]);
console.log(addSquare(3, 1));
```

I started by writing trace2 thinking that trace wouldn't work because "How can tap possibly know about n or x whatever?".

But trace does work and I do not understand how it can “inject” the x coming from the flow into the tap call. Any explanation will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `tap` is curried, which means if you don't pass enough arguments, it returns a function that still needs the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Silver Spoon Evaluation**

We'll just start with tracing the evaluation of

```js
addSquare(3, 1) // ...
```

Ok, here goes

```
= flow([add, trace('after add'), square]) (3, 1)
        add(3,1)
        4
             trace('after add') (4)
             tap(x => console.log(`== ${ 'after add' }:  ${ x }`)) (4)
             curry((interceptor, n) => { interceptor(n); return n; }) (x => console.log(`== ${ 'after add' }:  ${ x }`)) (4)
             (x => console.log(`== ${ 'after add' }:  ${ x }`)) (4); return 4;
             console.log(`== ${ 'after add' }:  ${ 4 }`); return 4;
~log effect~ "== after add: 4"; return 4
             4
                                 square(4)
                                 4 * 4
                                 16
= 16
```

So the basic "trick" you're having trouble seeing is that `trace('after add')` returns a function that's waiting for the last argument. This is because `trace` is a 2-parameter function that was *curried*.

---

**Futility**

I can't express how useless and misunderstood the [`flow`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/flow.js) function is

```js
function flow(funcs) {
  const length = funcs ? funcs.length : 0
  let index = length
  while (index--) {
    if (typeof funcs[index] != 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected a function')
    }
  }
  return function(...args) {
    let index = 0
    let result = length ? funcs[index].apply(this, args) : args[0]
    while (++index < length) {
      result = funcs[index].call(this, result)
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Sure, it *"works"* as it's described to work, but it allows you to create awful, fragile code.

- loop thru all provided functions to type check them
- loop thru all provided functions again to apply them
- for some reason, allow for the *first* function (and **only** the first function) to have special behaviour of accepting 1 **or more** arguments passed in
- all non-first functions will only accept 1 argument at most
- in the event an empty flow is used, all but your first input argument is discarded

Pretty weird f' contract, if you ask me. You should be asking:

- why are we looping thru twice ?
- why does the first function get special exceptions ?
- what do I gain with at the cost of this complexity ?

---

**Classic Function Composition**

Composition of two functions, `f` and `g` – allows data to seemingly teleport from state `A` directly to state `C`. Of course state `B` still happens behind the scenes, but the fact that we can remove this from our cognitive load is a tremendous gift.

[image: function composition]

Composition and currying play so well together because

1. function composition works best with unary (single-argument) functions
2. curried functions accept 1 argument per application

---

Let's rewrite your code now

```js
const add = a => b => a + b

const square = n => n * n;

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x))

const comp2 = comp (comp) (comp)

const addSquare = comp2 (square) (add)

console.log(addSquare(3)(1)) // 16
```

*"Hey you tricked me! That `comp2` wasn't easy to follow at all!"* – and I'm sorry. But it's because the function was doomed from the start. Why tho?

Because composition works best with unary functions! We tried composing a binary function `add` with a unary function `square`.

To better illustrate classical composition and how simple it can be, let's look at a sequence using *just* unary functions.

```js
const mult = x => y => x * y

const square = n => n * n;

const tap = f => x => (f(x), x)

const trace = str => tap (x => console.log(`== ${str}: ${x}`))

const flow = ([f,...fs]) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : flow (fs) (f(x))

const tripleSquare = flow([mult(3), trace('triple'), square])

console.log(tripleSquare(2))
// == "triple: 6"
// => 36
```

Oh, by the way, we reimplemented `flow` with a single line of code, too.

---

**Tricked again**

OK, so you probably noticed that the `3` and `2` arguments were passed in separate places. You'll think you've been cheated again.

```
const tripleSquare = flow([mult(3), trace('triple'), square])

console.log(tripleSquare(2)) //=> 36
```

But the fact of the matter is this: As soon as you introduce a single non-unary function into your function composition, you might as well refactor your code. Readability plummets immediately. There's absolutely no point in trying to keep the code point-free if it's going to hurt readability.

Let's say we had to keep both arguments available to your original `addSquare` function … what would that look like ?

```js
const add = x => y => x + y

const square = n => n * n;

const tap = f => x => (f(x), x)

const trace = str => tap (x => console.log(`== ${str}: ${x}`))

const flow = ([f,...fs]) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : flow (fs) (f(x))

const addSquare = (x,y) => flow([add(x), trace('add'), square]) (y)

console.log(addSquare(3,1))
// == "add: 4"
// => 16
```

OK, so we had to define `addSquare` as this

```
const addSquare = (x,y) => flow([add(x), trace('add'), square]) (y)
```

It's certainly not as *clever* as the lodash version, but it's *explicit* in how the terms are combined and there is virtually *zero* complexity.

In fact, the 7 lines of code here implements your entire program in less than it takes to implement just the lodash `flow` function alone.

---

**The fuss, and why**

Everything in your program is a trade off. I hate to see beginners struggle with things that should be simple. Working with libraries that make these things so complex is extremely disheartening – and don't even get me started on Lodash's [`curry`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/curry.js) implementation (including it's *insanely* complex [`createWrap`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/26ea38dcf4d0c856eb7ab62de4995ed81ba6cac7/.internal/createWrap.js))

My 2 cents: if you're just starting out with this stuff, libraries are a sledgehammer. They have their reasons for every choice they made, but know that each one involved a trade off. All of that complexity is not totally unwarranted, but it's not something you need to be concerned with as a beginner. Cut your teeth on basic functions and work your way up from there.

---

**Curry**

Since I mentioned `curry`, here's 3 lines of code that replace pretty much any practical use of Lodash's curry.

If you later trade these for a more complex implementation of curry, make sure you know what you're getting out of the deal – otherwise you just take on more overhead with little-to-no gain.

```js
// for binary (2-arity) functions
const curry2 = f => x => y => f(x,y)

// for ternary (3-arity) functions
const curry3 = f => x => y => z => f(x,y,z)

// for arbitrary arity
const partial = (f, ...xs) => (...ys) => f(...xs, ...ys)
```

---

**Two types of function composition**

One more thing I should mention: classic function composition applies functions right-to-left. Because some people find that hard to read/reason about, left-to-right function composers like `flow` and `pipe` have showed up in popular libs

[image: rtl vs ltr function composition]

- *Left-to-right composer*, `flow`, is aptly named because your eyes will *flow* in a spaghetti shape as your try to trace the data as it moves thru your program. (LOL)
- *Right-to-left* composer, `composer`, will make you feel like you're reading backwards at first, but after a little practice, it begins to feel very natural. It does not suffer from spaghetti shape data tracing.

Comment: @Tirke, your question is broader than you might realize and I've only scratched the surface with the topics presented here. If I can help in any other way, please just let me know ^_^

Comment: I couldn’t even dream about such a detailed and well-thought-out answer. This is exactly what I needed and I sure have a deeper understanding now.
I don’t have any questions on flow or composition for the moment, but I will remember you if I ever get stuck again in the wonderful world of fp :) Thanks 1000x.

Comment: @Tirke happy to help! I added one more note about RTL vs LTR function composition. Not surprisingly, `flow`'s entire existence makes your life more difficult – Once you come to know `compose` you will wonder why someone tried to "fix" what wasn't already broken.