# How to compose functions of varying arity using Lodash flow?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, composition

I want to do some function composition. I know already this:

If `f3(x)` shall be the same as `f1(f2(x))`
then `f3 = _.flowRight(f1,f2);`

If `f3(x,y)` shall be the same as `f1(x, f2(y))`
then …?

(The use case is the composition of node.js/express middleware functions.)

Comment: I wrote an answer yesterday about lodash's flow. I think you will find it very helpful wrt some functions aren't meant to be composed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42139851/633183

Comment: I wrote another answer an hour ago about composition in an existing code base. I think you will find it relevant to thsi topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42164779/633183

Comment: Your "problem" is that you're trying to compose functions of various *arity*; a unary function with a binary function. Function composition works best when unary functions are used exclusively. The short answer is `const f3 = (x,y) => f1(x, f2(y))` – let simple be simple.

Comment: @naomik thanks for your answer, and you're right about the arity (unary or binary, function with one, two or even more arguments). In my case I could argue, that all of my middleware functions *are binary*, so have *two arguments*: the filter value and the handler. So I am quite sure, it's 'generic' to my use-case.

Answer (score 6):

> In the following images, I use `{_}` as a placeholder for a value. Think of it as a *hole* in the code where we pass something in.

Ok let's imagine what your function would have to do...

[image: a bad dream]

- Does this seems like a generic transformation? ie, do you think we can use this in many places? – functional programming promotes building functions which are highly reusable and can be combined in various ways.
- What is the difference between `f1` and `f2`? `f1` is a unary function which will only get one arg, `f2` is a binary function which will get two. Are you going to remember which one goes in which place?
- What governs the position that `f1(x)` gets placed in `f2`?

  - Compare `f2(y,f1(x))` ...
  - to `f2(f1(x),y)`
  - is one of those more useful than the other?
  - are you going to remember which position `f1` gets?

---

Recall that function composition should be able to chain as many functions together as you want. To help you understand the futility of `someFunc`, let's imagine it accepting up to 3 functions and 3 arguments.

[image: a nigthmare]

- Is there even a pattern here? Maybe, but you still have the awkward unary function `f1` that only gets one arg, while `f2` and `f3` each get 2
- Is it true that `f2` and `f3` are going need the value of the previous function calls on the right side *always* ?

  - Compare `f3(z,f2(y,f1(x)))`
  - to `f3(f2(y,f1(x)),z)`
  - Maybe `f3` needs to chain left, but `f2` chains from the right?
  - I can't imagine your entire API of binary functions would magically need chained arguments in the same place
- You've already mixed unary with binary functions in your composition; why arbitrarily limit it to just functions of those type then? What about a function of 3 or more arguments?

---

**The answer is self-realizing**

Function composition is being misused here. Function composition pretty much only works when you're composing unary functions exclusive (functions accepting 1 argument each). It immediately breaks down and cannot be generalised when mixing in functions of higher arity.

Going back to your code now, if `f3` needs a name and it is the combination of `f1`, `f2`, and two parameters, it should be plainly expressed as …

```
const f3 = (x,y) => f1(x, f2(y))
```

Because it makes so many arbitrary choices, it *cannot* be generalized in any useful way. Just let it be as it is.

---

***"So is there any way to compose functions of varying arity?"***

Sure, there are a couple techniques of varied practicality. I'll demonstrate use of the highly practical `partial` function here

```js
const partial = (f,...xs) => (...ys) => f(...xs, ...ys)

const add = (x,y) => x + y

const mult = (x,y) => x * y

const sq = x => mult (x,x)

// R.I.P. lodash.flowRight
const compose = ([f,...fs]) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : f (compose (fs) (x))
                  
let f = compose([partial(add, 1), sq, partial(mult, 3)])

console.log(f(2))
// add(1, square(mult(3, 2)))
// add(1, square(6))
// add(1, 36)
// => 37
```

Oh, by the way, we replaced Lodash's `flowRight` (wrapper of the complex [`flow`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/flow.js)) with a single line of code.

Comment: It should be able to compose functions that have exactly the same arity

Comment: And what pattern do you suggest for binary functions? Ternary functions? N-ary functions?

Comment: have an array output of N length that matches the length of the arguments

Comment: you don’t need to alter `compose` to do that - just compose a call to `const apply = f => (xs = []) => f (...xs)`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a very specific requirement that may not have a lodash equivalent.

Why not just write your own helper function for this?

```js
function composeFuncs(f1, f2) {
  return function(x, y) {
    return f1.call(this, x, f2.call(this, y));
  };
}

var myObj = {
  add: function(val1, val2) {
    return this.myVal + val1 + val2
  },
  mult: function(val) {
    return this.myVal * val
  },
  myVal: 7
};

myObj.newFunc = composeFuncs(myObj.add, myObj.mult);

// 7 + 1 + 7 * 2 = 22
console.log(myObj.newFunc(1, 2));
```

**Edit:** Updated to handle `this` the same way `_.flowRight` does.

Comment: Of course I could do this, but I then probably have to take care of the handling of 'this' as _.flowRight from lodash is doing. As I am quite new to doing much in the functional programming way, I thought, there might be a well known pattern for something like what I need. :)

Comment: @matths Modified to include `this` propagation.  Could you give an example of where you want to use this? I'm not familiar of a a well-known pattern for this, but there might be one.

Comment: I am currently writing express/connect like middleware functions, e.g. one is  `method(m, handler)` where m can be get, post, put, etc. and another might be `path(p, handler)`. Composition should be `request(m, p, handler)` which runs `method(m, path(p, handler))`. Each middleware return value is a handler function by itself. I am not sure, I can explain well enough.

Comment: @matths in general, functional programming largely does not concern itself with context `this` – JS is multiparadigm and `this` is primarily suited for writing programs in OOP style