# Redux: Middleware to return the actions payload for functional programming

Tags: javascript, redux, functional-programming, ramda.js, redux-middleware

**TLDR:** Is the following middleware for Redux okay or is it a bad idea / bad practice? If it's bad, how else would you use `dispatch` with pipe or compose (in a declarative way)? *For ES6 version see further down.* I initially wanted to open on issue on the Redux GitHub, but it apparently only allows bug reports and refers you to StackOverflow ‍♂️

```
// Purpose: have dispatch return its payload so that it
// can be used in pipes or compositions
export default function createPayloadReturner() {
    return function wrapDispatchToAddPayloadReturn(next) {
        return function dispatchAndReturn(action) {
            function wrappedDispatch() {
                next(action);
                return action.payload;
            }
            if (action.payload) {
                return wrappedDispatch();
            }

            return next(action);
        };
    };
}
```

**Motivation**: I'm currently learning functional programming. I'm writing a React app with Redux for my state management and Ramda to help me with functional programming.

I have a function called `login` that is created by an `asyncPipe`. It takes the credentials, logs the user in, saves the token, and uses that token to make an authenticated GET request to the server. The guest request returns a list of one or more objects (houses).

```
// Pseudo-code-ish
import { prop } from 'ramda';

const asyncPipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce(async (y, f) => f(await y), x);

const login = asyncPipe(
  loginRequest,
  prop('token'),
  setToken,
  getHouses,
)

// later (currently without the middleware)
const houseList = await login(credentials);
```

Now comes the issue. First, I would like to `dispatch` the list of restaurants (`dispatch(addHouses(houseList))`). Next, if there are more than one houses I would like to navigate the user to a list screen so he can pick a house. If there is just one house I would like to immediately navigate him to that house and pick it. Picking means `dispatch(pickHouse(house))`.

I asked about this problem in general in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787024/ramda-is-there-a-way-to-fork-a-parameter-to-two-functions-during-pipe) question. A commenter suggested creating a middleware so that `dispatch` returns the respective actions payload and can be used in a pipe.

Therefore, using the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware), I wrote this:

```
export default () => next => action => {
    const wrappedDispatch = () => {
        next(action);
        return action.payload;
    };
    if (action.payload) {
        return wrappedDispatch();
    }

    return next(action);
};
```

Now you can use it in a `asyncPipe`, `pipe` or `compose` function.

Is this the correct way to return a payload? (I've tested it and the middleware seems to work.) Is this middleware okay, or does it violate some best practices?

Comment: if you want to go functional, then redux-observable is the way to go

Comment: Actually, stock redux's dispatch does return the exact action object it gets. It could be some other middleware mess it up.