# Function Composition With Monads...not working

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have some ugly data, that requires a lot of ugly null checks. My goal is to write a suite of functions to access/modify it in a point-free, declarative style, using the Maybe monad to keep null checks to a minimum. Ideally I would be able to use Ramda with the monads, but it's not working out so great.

This works:

```
const Maybe = require('maybe');
const R = require('ramda');
const curry = fn => (...args) => fn.bind(null, ...args);
const map = curry((fn, monad) => (monad.isNothing()) ? monad : Maybe(fn(monad.value())));
const pipe = (...fns) => acc => fns.reduce((m, f) => map(f)(m), acc);
const getOrElse = curry((opt, monad) => monad.isNothing() ? opt : monad.value());
const Either = (val, d) => val ? val : d;

const fullName = (person, alternative, index) => R.pipe(
  map(R.prop('names')),
  map(R.nth(Either(index, 0))),
  map(R.prop('value')),
  map(R.split('/')),
  map(R.join('')),
  getOrElse(Either(alternative, ''))
)(Maybe(person));
```

However, having to type out 'map()' a billion times doesn't seem very DRY, nor does it look very nice. I'd rather have a special pipe/compose function that wraps each function in a map().

Notice how I'm using R.pipe() instead of my custom pipe()? My custom implementation always throws an error, **'isNothing() is not a function,**' upon executing the last function passed to it.

I'm not sure what went wrong here or if there is a better way of doing this, but any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the data inside `person` look like?

Comment: What have you tested for composition? You should be able to do `R.compose(R.props(..), R.nth(..), R.split(...)` and then `R.map(composedFuncs, Maybe(person))`

Comment: Hint: in modern browsers `.bind(thisArg)` is incredibly fast. at the same time, `.bind(thisArg, ...funcArgs)` is awfully slow. Closures are a better (faster) alternative in this case: `const curry = fn => (...args) => (...brgs) => fn.apply(null, args.concat(brgs));`

Comment: That's the point where I dislike FP. When I have to twist and bend, just to fit the paradigm. I like a declarative style, because used right it doubles as commenting the code, but not if I have to use it for every single tiny step/operation/operator. I'd write your code as `const fullName = (person, alternative = "", index=0) => string( fetch(person, ["names", index, "value"]) ) .split("/").join("") || alternative;` where my two utilities `string` and `fetch` don't contain more code than all your utils. But this doesn't really fit the topic, or does it?

Comment: @atomrc The data looks like { names: [{value: 'Bob / Johnson', sources : { ... } }, {...etc.} ] }. None of the Ramda functions can access the Maybe value by themselves, so I'm trying to separate map somehow and use a custom compose/pipe function.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for reminding me of default arguments! I'm basically just trying to refactor old code that was kind of ugly and contained a ton of null checks, in order to add more features later without the headache. You're correct, I replaced it with another headache, but the word 'monad' sounds cool.

Comment: You might want to look at [`R.pipeK`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeK).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**first things first**

1. that `Maybe` implementation ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maybe)) is pretty much junk - you might want to consider picking an implementation that doesn't require you to implement the Functor interface (like you did with `map`) – I might suggest [Data.Maybe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data.maybe) from folktale. Or since you're clearly not afraid of implementing things on your own, make your own Maybe ^_^

---

2. Your `map` implementation is not suitably generic to work on any functor that implements the functor interface. Ie, yours *only* works with `Maybe`, but `map` *should* be generic enough to work with any *mappable*, if there is such a word.

   No worries tho, Ramda includes [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) in the box – just use that along with a `Maybe` that implements the `.map` method (eg Data.Maybe referenced above)

---

3. Your `curry` implementation doesn't curry functions quite right. It only works for functions with an arity of 2 – curry should work for any function length.

   ```
   // given, f
   const f = (a,b,c) => a + b + c

   // what yours does
   curry (f) (1) (2) (3) // => Error: curry(...)(...)(...) is not a function

   // because 
   curry (f) (1) (2) // => NaN

   // what it should do
   curry (f) (1) (2) (3) // => 6
   ```

   There's really no reason for you to implement `curry` on your own if you're already using Ramda, as it already includes [curry](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry)

---

3. Your `pipe` implementation is mixing concerns of function composition and mapping functors (via use of `map`). I would recommend reserving `pipe` specifically for function composition.

   Again, not sure why you're using Ramda then reinventing a lot of it. Ramda already includes [`pipe`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe)

   Another thing I noticed

   ```
   // you're doing
   R.pipe (a,b,c) (Maybe(x))

   // but that's the same as
   R.pipe (Maybe,a,b,c) (x)
   ```

---

4. That `Either` you made is probably not the Either functor/monad you're thinking of. See [`Data.Either`](https://github.com/folktale/data.either) (from folktale) for a more complete implementation

---

5. Not a single monad was observed – your question is about function composition with monads but you're only using functor interfaces in your code. Some of the confusion here might be coming from the fact that `Maybe` implements `Functor` *and* `Monad`, so it can behave as both (and like any other interface it implements) ! The same is true for `Either`, in this case.

   You might want to see [`Kleisli category`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category) for monadic function composition, though it's probably not relevant to you for this particular problem.

---

**functional interfaces are governed by laws**

Your question is born out of a lack of exposure/understanding of the functor laws – What these mean is *if* your data type adheres to these laws, only *then* can it can be said that your type *is* a functor. Under all other circumstances, you might be dealing with something *like* a functor, but not actually a functor.

> **functor laws**
>
> where `map :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, `id` is the identity function `a -> a`, and `f :: b -> c` and `g :: a -> b`
>
> ```
> // identity
> map(id) == id
>
> // composition 
> compose(map(f), map(g)) == map(compose(f, g))
> ```

What this says to us is that we can either compose multiple calls to `map` with each function individually, or we can compose all the functions first, and then `map` *once*. – Note on the left-hand side of the composition law how we call `.map` twice to apply two functions, but on the right-hand side `.map` was only called once. The result of each expression is identical.

> **monad laws**
>
> While we're at it, we can cover the monad laws too – again, *if* your data type obeys these laws, only *then* can it be called a monad.
>
> where `mreturn :: Monad m => a -> m a`, `mbind :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`
>
> ```
> // left identity
> mbind(mreturn(x), f) == f(x)
>
> // right identity
> mbind(m, mreturn) == m
>
> // associativity
> mbind(mbind(m, f), g) == mbind(m, x => mbind(f(x), g))
> ```

It's maybe even a little easier to see the laws using Kleisli composition function, `composek` – now it's obvious that Monads truly obey the associativity law

> **monad laws defined using Kleisli composition**
>
> where `composek :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)`
>
> ```
> // kleisli left identity
> composek(mreturn, f) == f
>
> // kleisli right identity
> composek(f, mreturn) == f
>
> // kleisli associativity
> composek(composek(f, g), h) == composek(f, composek(g, h))
> ```

---

**finding a solution**

So what does all of this mean for you? In short, you're doing more work than you have to – especially implementing a lot of the things that already comes with your chosen library, Ramda. Now, there's nothing wrong with that (in fact, I'm a huge proponent of this if you audit many of my 
other answers on the site), but it can be the source of confusion if you get some of the implementations wrong.

Since you seem mostly hung up on the `map` aspect, I will help you see a simple transformation. This takes advantage of the Functor composition law illustrated above:

Note, this uses `R.pipe` which composes left-to-right instead of right-to-left like `R.compose`. While [I prefer right-to-left composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42139851/633183), the choice to use `pipe` vs `compose` is up to you – it's just a notation difference; either way, the laws are fulfilled.

```
// this
R.pipe(map(f), map(g), map(h), map(i)) (Maybe(x))

// is the same as
Maybe(x).map(R.pipe(f,g,h,i))
```

I'd like to help more, but I'm not 100% sure what your function is actually trying to do.

1. starting with `Maybe(person)`
2. read `person.names` property
3. get the first index of `person.names` – is it an array or something? or the first letter of the name?
4. read the `.value` property?? We're you expecting a monad here? (look at `.chain` compared to `.map` in the `Maybe` and `Either` implementations I linked from folktale)
5. split the value on `/`
6. join the values with `''`
7. if we have a value, return it, otherwise return some alternative

That's my best guess at what's going on, but I can't picture your data here or make sense of the computation you're trying to do. If you provide more concrete data examples and expected output, I might be able to help you develop a more concrete answer.

---

**remarks**

I too was in your boat a couple of years ago; just getting into functional programming, I mean. I wondered how all the little pieces could fit together and actually produce a human-readable program.

The majority of benefits that functional programming provides can only be observed when functional techniques are applied to an entire system. At first, it will feel like you had to introduce tons of dependencies just to rewrite one function in a "functional way". But once you have those dependencies in play in *more* places in your program, you can start slashing complexity left and right. It's really cool to see, but it takes a while to get your program (and your head) there.

In hindsight, this might not be a great answer, but I hope this helped you in some capacity. It's a very interesting topic to me and I'm happy to assist in answering any other questions you have ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the super in-depth answer! Funny how you managed to narrow down the source of my confusion, even though I was not aware enough of the terminology/practice to formulate it correctly in the first place.

Comment: it's more impressive to me that you saw a pattern and recognized that it could be improved, even if you couldn't immediately see how. It's always fun to learn that there's an elegant strategy/technique to handle a particular problem ^_^

Comment: Well it's impressive when people know what they're talking about, too :). Do you have any recommendations for further reading/other learning materials? Also, any opinion on Clojure for learning FP? Thanks again for your great answer.

Comment: JavaScript has first-class functions making it great to learn many functional concepts. If JavaScript is already comfortable for you, I would check out [Professor Frisby's Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/)  – Or, if you want to explore some of the basics in a very learner-friendly language, I would recommend [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP)](https://github.com/sarabander/sicp)

Comment: ... and SICP's [accompanying video lectures](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/) from Sussman/Abelson – wrt Clojure, it's a very nice language from what I've seen, but I've avoided spending too much time with it because I particularly loathe all things Java (including JVM).

Comment: (In hindsight) - No, this is a great answer, clearing up all sorts of issues, some I thought about when I saw this earlier but was on a phone, and some I hadn't even noticed.  Two corrections:  "`// but that's the same as R.pipe (Maybe,a,b,c) (x)`" (The `Maybe` was at the wrong end for `pipe`.)   And " and `f` and `g` are functions (of type `(b -> c)` and `(a -> b)`, respectively.)" (`(a -> b)` does not compose with itself.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet heaps thanks for the technical audit! I did indeed cross my wires between `compose` and `pipe` wrt composition order. Good catch on the function types too – I always appreciate your comments ^_^