# Rambda multiply two numbers then add result to third number

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, rambda.js

I'm new to functional programming and am trying to implement a multiplication -> addition function using in typescript with [rambda](https://ramdajs.com/).

I want a function that takes three numbers, multiplies two together, then adds the result to the third, like so: `f(a, b, c) = a + (b * c)`. Here is the progress I've made so far:

Imperative style

```js
const f = (a: number, b: number, c: number) => a + b * c;
```

Functional style

```js
const add = (a: number) => (b: number) => a + b;
const mul = (a: number) => (b: number) => a * b;
const f = (a: number, b: number, c: number) => add(a)(mul(b)(c));
```

The problem with the above solution is the lack of readability of the function `f`, which is why I am trying to implement the same with Rambda. What I *want* to be able to say is something like `const f = R.pipe(mul, add);`, but I'm not sure how to define the functions `add` and `mul` to allow that.

Here is what I tried:

```js
const add = (a: number) => (b: number) => a + b;
const mul = (a: number) => (b: number) => a * b;
const f = R.pipe(mul, add);
```

And the resulting error:

```
Argument of type '(a: number) => (b: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => number'.
  Type '(b: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: https://remedajs.com/docs#pipe: pipe takes the data first and then the operations to perform. You have not given any data.

Comment: @NaitikMundra I think that's a different library. I'm using rambda's pipe function https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe

Comment: Oh, Sorry, did not realize that. It would probably be prudent to add a link to the library you are using in the question.

Comment: Ah! Just saw your code. Does `(a: number, b: number)` instead of `(a: number) => (b: number)` work?

Comment: @NaitikMundra added a link. So that works if I only change the `mul` function to `const mul = (a: number, b: number) => a * b;`. Now I can call it like so: `console.log(f(2, 3)(4)); // 2 * 3 + 4`. Seem to be getting closer, is there a way to make it so that all three arguments can be passed in at the same time?

Comment: Not in the way you hope. This is because you are passing the arguments to different functions. I write Haskell, not TS, so I will be unable to help you with the code, but what you want to do if you will always put it in the same order is to define f as the following: f takes arguments a,b,c. `f = add( c, mul(a,b)).`

Comment: Fair enough, makes sense, thanks! Out of curiosity, mind sharing how something like this would look like written in Haskell? (if it's not too much trouble!)

Comment: Nope never trouble to write haskell. Here you go(add is already defined in haskell. That is why I am using add'). `add' a b = a+b`. `mul a b = a * b`. Now, you could do: ```f a b c= add c $ a `mul` b```. The `$` gives precedence to argument on right. You could replace it with brackets if you wanted to. Types are inferred in haskell, so I did not bother to write them manually, but it can be done. For eg, `add::Int->Int->Int` means `add` takes 2 Integers and returns an Integer.

Answer (score 2):

**readability first**

Function composition is a technique that works best with unary functions. That's not to say you *can't* compose binary or ternary functions, it's just that it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

```js
const f = (a, b, c) =>
  add(a, mul(b, c))
```

That's it, you're done! And the readability is fantastic.

***"but mom, I want pipe"***

If you insist on using `compose` (or `pipe`) you can remove one point by partially applying `add` and `mul` -

```js
const g = a => b =>
  compose(add(a), mul(b))
```

Related Q&A: [How to understand curry and function composition in Lodash flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42139851/633183)